# Как вставить новую строку после строк с номером p в матрице?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Написал я прогу, которая заменяет строку матрицы с номером `p` на другую строку. Все работает. Но теперь поставлена другая задача, вставить эту же новую строку после строки с номером `p`. То есть нужно расширить, раздвинуть матрицу и засунуть туда новую строку. Как это сделать? Хелп.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int d[4][4],i,j,k;

    int a[4],b[4],p,g,el;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            d[i][j] = rand()%50-1; // заполняем матрциу
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                printf("%4i ",d[i][j]); // выводим матрицу на экран
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "Fill array \n";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        a[i] = rand()%12-1; // массив a - это новая строка, которую нужно будет вставить
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        b[i] = rand()%10-1; // а это массив b - это новый столбец, который тоже нужно будет вставить
    }

    cout << "Number str 'p': ";
    cin >> p; // после которой строки нужно вставлять новую строку
    cout << "Number col 'g': ";
    cin >> g; // после которого столбца нужно вставлять новый столбец
    cout << "\n";

    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        d[p][j] = a[j]; // тут мы заменяем, а нужно вставить
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        d[i][g] = b[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                printf("%4i ",d[i][j]);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Использовать динамические массивы, а не статические

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как вам надо "расширять" матрицу, то вам нужно использовать динамические массивы. Если вы с ними не сталкивались, то можно почитать примеры [тут](https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-dynamic-arrays/), например.

Ниже прикладываю код, где по функция разнесены созданием матрицы (все значения сразу инициализируются нулями для простоты), удаление матрицы (важно - не забывать высвобождать память после окончания работы с ячейками памяти), вставка строки.

Вставка строки в данном случае реализована как создание динамического массива, идентичного по размеру исходному, но на одну строку больше. В этот массив мы переносим значения из изначального, но на место требуемой строки мы вставляем значение не из исходной матрицы, а из введенного пользователем одномерного массива. Но надо помнить, что тогда при следующем шаге `i` для исходного массива будет уже указывать не на ту строку, которую нам надо скопировать, поэтому вводится сдвиг `shift`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void createMatrix(int**& X, int rows, int cols)
{// создание матрицы
    X = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        X[i] = new int[cols] {0};
    }
}

void displayMatrix(int** X, int rows, int cols)
{//вывод матрицы
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << X[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void deleteMatrix(int**& X, int rows)
{// освобождение памяти
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] X[i];
    }
    delete[] X;
}

void insertRows(int**& X, int& rows, int cols, int posr)
{//вставка строки
    int** buff;
    int *insertRow = new int [cols];
    int shift = 0;
    createMatrix(buff, rows + 1, cols);

    cout << "ROW TO INSERT: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        cin >> insertRow[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows + 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == posr)
        {
            shift = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                buff[i][j] = insertRow[j];
        } else 
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            buff[i][j] = X[i - shift][j];
        }
    }
    deleteMatrix(X, rows);
    rows++;
    X = buff;
}




int main()
{
    int rows, cols, pos;
    cout << "Enter matrix size: ";
    cin >> rows >> cols;
    int** M;

    createMatrix(M, rows, cols);
    displayMatrix(M, rows, cols);

    cout << "Enter pos to insert: ";
    cin >> pos;

    insertRows(M, rows, cols, pos);
    displayMatrix(M, rows, cols);
    deleteMatrix(M, rows);
    return 0;
}
```